# How put a mask in a TextInputCell?

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-bootstrap

I have a TextInputCell in a Column, like this:

```
TextInputCell textCell = new TextInputCell();
    Column<EffortCost, String> hourColumn = new Column<EffortCost, String>(textCell) {  
        public String getValue(EffortCost object) {
            String formatted = NumberFormat.getFormat("0.00").format(object.getHours());

            return formatted;
        }
    };
```

My string returned: "1.00" if I wrote "1". I want the same result, but I don't wanna formated the string, I want my widget doing this in a moment I put the text in the TextInputCell, in other words, I want format the string automatically while I write the text in my TextInputCell. This would be like a "MaskedTextInputCell". How can I do this? Can I see some examples?

Thanks for attention.

Comment: So, what are you going to display if a user types "I love cats" in this cell?

Comment: @AndreiVolgin I'm not validating any cell, sorry. If I write "I love cats" an exception is displayed. 

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "I love Cats"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a FieldUpdater for your hourColumn.
It has update() method which fires when value of a cell in this column changes. For example:

```
hourColumn.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<EffortCost, String>() {
@Override
public void update(int index, EffortCost object, String value) {
    // do something when value changes
    // return NumberFormat.getFormat("0.00").format(object.getHours());
}
});
```

every time when you enter numbers it will format and update.

Comment: This is the correct solution. Note that when a user types "1", you don't know yet whether he wanted to type 12 or 120. You can only format the number when a user "leaves" a cell, and the update() method is fired.

Comment: @AndreiVolgin yes. your right. when executing code we can easily track these.